# Installing Microcode for dummies new install of Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, software-installation, microcode

When I try to install Ubuntu I get a TSC_Deadline due to Errata error stating that I need to update to microcode 0x22 or later. Then the install gets stuck on the splash screen.

I have read a lot of post on this and they are all Greek to me. I am a very comfortable windows user with no Linux experience so I need the answer to be written for a 10-year-old.

Much of what is written appears to refer to updating the microcode using Linux code but I cannot get it installed so I cannot fix it using Linux. And I have no idea what GRUB is which seems to be important in this discussion.

I appreciate your time in helping get this fixed.

I'm not sure what computer info you need to help with this but have an Asus machine running Windows 10 with an i5 intel chip. Please just let me know what other info you need. Thanks again. Paul

Comment: you are going to need to provide some more info. what version are you trying to install? are you installing from USB? can you boot into the "try Ubuntu before installing"

Comment: " Then the install gets stuck on the splash screen. " That has nothing to do with "TSC_Deadline due to Errata error stating" and is a separate issue. That notice is just that; a notice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually *installing* Ubuntu, you just need to install the intel-microcode package, and reboot.  This will fix things on a still-supported Ubuntu release.

If you are running Ubuntu from CD, DVD or USB, someone needs to generate an updated CD/DVD/USB image with the updated microcode for you, and you need to start using the updated image.